# How do I make my loading image centered on my page?

Tags: css, jsf-2, richfaces

I have a web application which uses jsf-2 and richfaces.
I wanted to put a loading mask over the page while waiting for ajax responses (when clicking on menu items), so I added the loading image to the template that also defines the menu items :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    template="/templates/main-template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="html_head">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"
            href="${request.contextPath}/resources/css/main.css" />
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="title">Title</ui:define>

    <ui:define name="top_menu">
        <li id="product_tab" class="process-a-tab"><h:commandLink
                action="#{AViewController.doView()}" onclick="document.getElementById('loading').style.display='block'">#{msgApp.a_tab}</h:commandLink>
        </li>
        <li id="mgmt_unit_tab" class="process-a-tab"><h:commandLink
                action="#{BViewController.doView()}" onclick="document.getElementById('loading').style.display='block'">#{msgApp.b_tab}</h:commandLink>
        </li>
        <img id="loading" src="resources/img/loading.gif" style="display:none" />

    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="head">
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="footer">
        <h:outputText value="Application v 4.0" />
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

The css for `#loading` :

```
#loading {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;;
  opacity: 0.4;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

The menu template above is then included in other pages :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    template="/templates/page-template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="title">#{msgApp.title}</ui:define>

    <ui:define name="breadcrumb">
        <ui:include src="bread_crumb.xhtml" />
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="amount">
        <ui:include src="amount.xhtml" />
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="subTotal">
        <ui:include src="sub_total.xhtml" />
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="total">
        <ui:include src="total.xhtml" />
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
        <ui:include src="content.xhtml" />
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

The problem I have is that the loading image, instead of being centered on the page, is centered on the surrounding `<ui:define>`, and that makes it barely visible.

How do I center it on the page ?

Comment: Try position: fixed; for loader.

Comment: Keep in mind that client-side **ALL** is html, css and javascript. So posting that is way more relevant than the xhtml (as you can see from the answers)

Answer (score 1):

Use css flexbox:

```
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally what I usually do is have an overlay element thats `position: fixed;` and is `width: 100%; height: 100vh;`.  Then make it a flexbox with `justify-content: center; align-items: center;`.  Then put your loading image in that element.  The element covers the whole viewport and your image will be in the center of that.